# How to list my private project from gitlab via personal token

Tags: gitlab-api

I got a problem  when i want to got my private project from my gitlab via API .

I have registered a private token with all function , but when i use it to list my project , it return public without private .
I read Doc , only return public means that accessed without authentication , but i use the way same as example in Doc.

Doc  example of use token in cli

```
 curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"
```

Doc example of list project

```
GET /users/:user_id/projects
```

my Cli

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:MyToken" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/Myusername/projects"
```

Is my format error ?

thank for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the list of your projects "owned projects private and public" by adding this attribute :

> owned=true

to this

> url : https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:MyToken""https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/?owned=true"
```

for only private projects you must add this attribute

> visibility=private

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:MyToken""https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/?owned=true&visibility=private"
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects